# Typescript: create instance in base class of a type defined in extending class / dynamic return type

Tags: typescript

I have Base class which has style and styleType properties defined. There is a Better class which extends Base class and it overrides styleType with another value.

Is it possible in the Base class to create instance of style which is of styleType defined in Better class?

And, a second question - can getter of style in Base class return the correct type (BetterStyle if it's BetterBase instance) of style?

```
class Base {
    styleType:typeof Style = Style;
    private _style:Style;

    constructor(){
        this._style = new this.styleType();
    }
    // how to define return type so that it would beof styleType?
    public get style():Style{
        return this._style;
    }
}

class Style{
    public color;
}

class BetterBase extends Base{
    styleType:typeof BetterStyle =  BetterStyle;
}

class BetterStyle extends Style{
    public betterColor;
}

var betterBase = new BetterBase();
betterBase.style.color = "#FF0000";
console.log(betterBase.style); // incorrect, outputs Style, not BetterStyle
console.log(betterBase.styleType);
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20styleType%3Atypeof%20Style%20%3D%20Style%3B%0D%0A%09private%20_style%3AStyle%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor()%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._style%20%3D%20new%20this.styleType()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20how%20to%20define%20return%20type%20so%20that%20it%20would%20be%20of%20styleType%3F%0D%0A%09public%20get%20style()%3AStyle%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this._style%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Style%7B%0D%0A%09public%20color%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BetterBase%20extends%20Base%7B%0D%0A%09styleType%3Atypeof%20BetterStyle%20%3D%20%20BetterStyle%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BetterStyle%20extends%20Style%7B%0D%0A%09public%20betterColor%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20betterBase%20%3D%20new%20BetterBase()%3B%0D%0AbetterBase.style.color%20%3D%20%22%23FF0000%22%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(betterBase.style)%3B%20%2F%2F%20incorrect%2C%20outputs%20Style%2C%20not%20BetterStyle%0D%0Aconsole.log(betterBase.styleType)%3B%0D%0A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you're doing is calling a virtual method from a constructor, which is a no-no because the base class constructor has to finish before derived class initialization can happen. The solution is to defer that execution until later so that the derived class can overwrite the base class value:

```
class Base {
    styleType:typeof Style = Style;
    private _style:Style;

    constructor(){ }

    // Lazy initialization
    public get style():Style{
        return this._style || (this.style = new this.styleType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this indeed solves first issue (correct type of style is created). What about 2nd - is it possible that style getter return type would be BetterStyle (if it's BetterBase instance)?

Comment: Not currently possible to make that automatic. You could make `Base` generic and require derivatives to provide a concrete type, though.

Comment: By adding getter to each class which extends Base, right?